# Discord.js | How to read a number in a message?

Tags: discord.js, parseint

I'm trying to make a game for my discord bot: bot chooses a random number and then, user tries to find number by guidance of the bot. I tried this thing but when I send a message (I send a number) it turns NaN. Why this happens and how can I fix it?

```js
        let randomNumber = (Math.floor( Math.random() * (100)))
        let usersAnswer = parseInt(message.content)

        if (!message.author.bot && message.content === "!pick number"){
                message.reply("I kept! :check: ").then(j => {
                    message.channel.awaitMessages(( message, user) => (user.id === message.author.id && randomNumber < usersAnswer || randomNumber > usersAnswer),
                        {max: 1, time: 10000}).then(j => {
                        if (usersAnswer < randomNumber) {
                            message.reply("Increase! :arrow_up:" + usersAnswer) //I add usersAnswer to the bot's message because I want to see what it reads my message like in Discord
                        }
                        else {
                            message.reply("Decrease! :arrow_down:" + usersAnswer)
                        }
                    })
            })
        }
```

Comment: I would recommend using Number() instead of parseInt()

Comment: For parseInt() you need to set a radix: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) you need to set a radix before using this method. I took 10 as an example.

```js
let usersAnswer = parseInt(message.content, 10)

        if (!message.author.bot && message.content === "!pick number"){
                message.reply("I kept! :check: ").then(j => {
                    message.channel.awaitMessages(( message, user) => (user.id === message.author.id && randomNumber < usersAnswer || randomNumber > usersAnswer),
                        {max: 1, time: 10000}).then(j => {
                        if (usersAnswer < randomNumber) {
                            message.reply("Increase! :arrow_up:" + usersAnswer) //I add usersAnswer to the bot's message because I want to see what it reads my message like in Discord
                        }
                        else {
                            message.reply("Decrease! :arrow_down:" + usersAnswer)
                        }
                    })
            })
        }
```

Or you could also simply use `Number()`:

```js
let usersAnswer = Number(message.content)

        if (!message.author.bot && message.content === "!pick number"){
                message.reply("I kept! :check: ").then(j => {
                    message.channel.awaitMessages(( message, user) => (user.id === message.author.id && randomNumber < usersAnswer || randomNumber > usersAnswer),
                        {max: 1, time: 10000}).then(j => {
                        if (usersAnswer < randomNumber) {
                            message.reply("Increase! :arrow_up:" + usersAnswer) //I add usersAnswer to the bot's message because I want to see what it reads my message like in Discord
                        }
                        else {
                            message.reply("Decrease! :arrow_down:" + usersAnswer)
                        }
                    })
            })
        }
```

If I were you I would add a check if the usersAnswer is even a Number otherwise the output could also be NaN.)
You could do this by simply adding the following line:

```js
if (isNaN(usersAnswer)) return message.reply('This is not a number');
```